# Send two emails using mail() with different bodies

Tags: php, email

I've read a few answers that suggest this is possible by simply using two mail() calls with unique variables. In the PHP code below I get the second email, but not the first.

I'm at a loss as to what could be the issue. Hopefully it's blindingly obvious.

```
$to = $visitor_email;
        $subject = "Get started";
        $from = $your_email;

        $body = "Test";

        $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
        $headers .= "MessageID: <" . md5('HELLO'.(idate("U")-1000000000).uniqid())."@test.com>";


        mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );


        $to2 = $your_email_2;
        $subject2 = "Form";
        $from2 = $your_email_2;
        $ip = isset( $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ] ) ? $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ] : '';

        $body2 =
            "IP: $ip\n\n" .
        "Name: $name\n" .
        "Company: $company\n" .
        "Email: $visitor_email_2 \n";


        $headers2 = "From: $from2 \r\n";
        $headers2 .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email_2 \r\n";
        $headers2 .= "MessageID: <" . md5('HELLO'.(idate("U")-1000000000).uniqid())."@example.com>";

        if ( mail( $to2, $subject2, $body2, $headers2 ) ) {
            header( 'Location: success.html' );
        } else {
            header( 'Location: fail.html' );
        }
```

Comment: Is `$to` a valid email address? Is it your email address? If the answer to either of those is "no", then it's no wonder you didn't receive an email.

Comment: Yes, $to is a valid email address. I tested with just one of these mail() calls and they work independently, just not together.

Comment: Do you get an email if you `exit();` after the first call to `mail()`?

Comment: is the `from` email address from your domain?

Comment: Sending email "From" a domain you don't control is a really bad plan, it's liable to be rejected as being fraudulent, which it is.

Comment: Tip: Instead of tripping over yourself here with `$body` vs. `$body2` and so on, make two functions each with their own local variables. This can really help clean up clutter.